# Facfactorial Function

Tags: r, recursion, shiny, factorial, shiny-server

I am quite new to Shiny, but I am trying to implement a recursive factorial function into the R

Here is the code I am trying to implement:

```
recursive.factorial <- function(x) {
    # if the value of x is 0 or 1, then 1 is returned
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) {
    return (1)
  }
  else {
    return (x * recursive.factorial(x - 1)) # recursive function to calculate the factorial
  }
}
recursive.factorial(5)
```

Is it even possible to put something like this in Shiny?

Thanks

Comment: FYI - I just want to have an input for the factorial function in the sidepanel, and then it returns the result in the mainPanel.

Comment: Of course it is possible ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(shiny)

recursive.factorial <- function(x) {
  # if the value of x is 0 or 1, then 1 is returned
  if (x == 0 || x == 1) {
return (1)
}
  else {
return (x * recursive.factorial(x - 1)) # recursive function to calculate the factorial
} 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
),
mainPanel(textOutput("value"))
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({
  print(recursive.factorial(input$obs))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Thought I had to do some fancy things in server.R to make it work.

Comment: Np! You can define functions/load data/set variables all before you write the ui/server part